# update timestamp on user logout not working

Tags: php

```
function logout() 
{

$session_ida = $_SESSION['user']['name'];

$query3 = "UPDATE 'userlog' set 'logout' = CURTIME() where username = 
        '$session_ida'";

mysqli_query($db,$query3);

unset($_SESSION['user']['name']);

session_destroy();

header("location: login.php");

}
```

Comment: $db doesn't exist in this scope.  Enable error reporting and always include those errors in your questions.

Comment: Pass $db as an element to the function call .

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the variable `$db` yet. I'll bet that you defined it in a different scope - however, as this is a separate function, this variable isn't directly accessible.